# Redirect after create or update node

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

How to redirect to certain Path after create/update specific Content type node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by

1. Make sure the ?destination parameter in your url is filled out. This will redirect you to the page defined in the destination parameter.
2. Use the [node save redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect) module. This module allows you to configure the redirect path per node type after saving a node.

[Node Save redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect) module.

This module provides a method of specifying a location to take the user after saving a piece of content.

A set of radios buttons are added to the submission vertical tab on the content type edit form.

The available options are.

> Default - Default behaviour
>  Return to Edit page after saving
>   Return to content overview page (assuming the user has access
>   permissions
>  Re-redirect to another location. (any valid drupal
>   path)